# SED replace spaces and caps between two known words

Tags: unix, sed

I am trying to replace all occurrences of myURL="different text Capitalized" in a text file with myURL="different_text_capitalized", and the text in between is different in each case.  Having trouble wrapping my head around it.  Here's what I have so far:

```
sed -i "s/myURL\".*\"/myUrl\"$VAROFSOMEKIND/g" file.text
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed (the use of which is implied by the '`-i`' option), at least, you can use '`\L`' to do the case-conversion.

```
sed -i 's/myURL="\([^"]*\)"/myURL="\L\1"/g' file.text
```

It is considerably harder (or my brain has frozen) to do a substitute of spaces for underscores on just the URL text when there could be other material on the same line with spaces in it.

I'd probably use Perl:

```
#!/bin/perl -p
if (m/(.*myURL=")([^"]*)(".*)/)
{
    my($bow, $mid, $aft) = ($1, lc($2), $3);
    $mid =~ s/ /_/g;
    $_ = "$bow$mid$aft\n";
}
```

That's a bit close to the infamous Perl 'line-noise', but...

- The '`-p`' means that Perl reads a line, executes the script on it, and prints the result; the line is read into `$_`.
- The regular expression splits the line into three pieces; the material up to the double quote after 'myURL='; the material inside the double quotes; and the material after the closing double quote (excluding the newline).
- The triple assignment gives names to the three matched sections, but converts the middle section to lower-case in the process.
- The substitute replaces blanks with underscores over the middle section.
- The assignment glues it all back together again, reinstating the dropped newline.
- Perl automatically prints out `$_`.

Comment: @Dennis; thanks, and I suppose that the Perl script should be appropriately modified (while loop for one, some decoration on the regex for the other).

Answer (score 0):

This monster will only work on the first URL on each line (which is also true of Jonathan Leffler's `sed` command - but a `g` modifier would fix his). It will change the text between a pair of quotes to lowercase and substitute underscores for the spaces within:

```
sed 's/myURL="\([^"]*\)"/myURL="\L\n\1\n"/;h;s/[^\n]*\n\([^\n]*\)\n.*/\1/;s/ /_/g;x;G;s/\([^\n]*\)\n[^\n]*\n\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/' inputfile
```